# im having a syntax error when querying postgres db through psycopg in python

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am getting a sql query error when running the below code. for some reasons this code runs nicely on some files but gives error on few of them.

I am trying to return values from a postgres db while connecting it through python. First query runs fine but the second one gives syntax error.

```
import pandas, psycopg2, pandas.io.sql 

order_list_s = df_s['ORDER'].unique().astype(str)
order_id_s = tuple(order_list_s.tolist()) # to get the list into tuple as db accepts tuple,str but not lists.

order_list_m = df_m['ORDER'].unique().astype(str)
order_id_m = tuple(order_list_m.tolist())

sql_date_tup = '01-01-2019'

connection = psycopg2.connect("host='dba' port=1234 dbname=name user=me password='pass'")
sql_u = """select "demand", "sid" from "global" where "wh" = 'UL' and "file date" >= {}  and "demand" in {};""".format(sql_date_tup, order_id_s)
sid_u = psql.read_sql(sql_u, connection)

sql_m = """select "demand", "sid" from "global" where "wh" = 'MI' and "file date" >= {}  and "demand" in {};""".format(sql_date_tup, order_id_m)
sid_m = psql.read_sql(sql_m, connection)

connection.close()
```

expected is to get 2 dataframes, sid_u and sid_m, but second query gives below error:

```
line 1431, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...MI' and "file date" >= '2019-05-02'  and "demand" in ();
```

Comment: Never use string formating with SQL queries they will lead to problems with quoting (best case) or SQL injections (worst case). Please read http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters .

Comment: It would appear `order_list_m` is empty when you run this code.